# Returning to the activity after logging into facebook

Tags: android, facebook

My question is how the user can return automatically to the activity he was using after logging into facebook ...

I mean that there are some activities that need to log into facebook, so the user moves into the login page . but when the user finishes it doesn't return to the application 
How can be this solved?

Answer (score 1):

it is up to your app to detect the url changes in the webview , intercept the facebook response , and then if success restart the pending operation that is why you would consider ask for login at startup and avoid all that complexity